# ActionScript 3.0 ray - shape intersection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, collision-detection, intersection

given a MovieClip containing a vectorshape (loaded from the library) - is there a way to check whether a line (from point(x1,y2) to point(x2,y2) intersects this shape?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the shape. If it's a simple geometric shape (or you can use one for collision), then you can use one of the hundreds of ray/shape collision methods on the net.

If it's a very specific shape, then one of the things you can do is step along your ray and do hitTestPoint() calls on your shape. Something like this (rough):

```
var ray:Point = new Point( x2 - x1, y2 - y1 ); // get the ray

// we want to check in, say 10 steps. depending on the length of the ray, you can increase/decrease this
var steps:int = 10;

// scale the ray
ray.x /= steps;
ray.y /= steps;

// step along the ray
var start:Point = new Point( x1, y1 );
for( var i:int = 0; i < steps; i++ )
{
    // hit test against the shape
    if( myShape.hitTestPoint( start.x, start.y, true ) )
    {
        // it's intersecting, do something
        break;
    }

    // it didn't intersect, keep going
    start.x += ray.x;
    start.y += ray.y;
}
```

Comment: yes - it's a specific shape. can I also somehow figure out the exact intersection point?

Comment: Make your step smaller, make the intersection code become a function and make it return it's current point.